# Растяжка блоков по вертикали

Tags: css3, css

Всем привет, есть шаблон в котором есть блок `conteiner`  а в нём два блока `sidebar` и content.

```
<div id="conteiner">
    <div id="sidebar">
    </div>
    <div id="content">
    </div>
</div>
```

Подскажите, как сделать так чтоб с наполнением контента, увеличевался и `sidebar` растягиваясь по всей высоте `conteinera`

Пробывал устанавливать `height:100%` не помогает

Comment: А для чего тебе их надо растягивать? Если надо сделать, что-то вроде двух колон разного цвета - можно и без растягивания этого добиться...

Answer (score 1):

Если на чистом css это делать, то есть несколько способов, каждый из которых имеет свои плюсы и минусы и применяется не во всех ситуациях. [Вот один из способов.](http://jsfiddle.net/mnEkq/)
С некоторыми другими можно ознакомиться [здесь.](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/equal-height-columns/) Если JQuery вам не враг, то http://jsfiddle.net/s53EH/

Answer (score 0):

если вы его не ограничиваете, то он должен растягиваться. Приведите css код.

Comment: #conteiner
{
 width:100%;
 min-height:500px;
 position:relative;
 border:1px solid black
}
#content
{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 min-height:500px;
 position:relative;
 text-align:justify;
 border:1px solid black
}
#content p
{
 margin-right:15px
}
#content p img
{
 float:left
}
.sidebar
{
 width:200px;
 height:auto !important;
 min-height:500px;
 float:left
}
.sidebar ul
{
 width:100%;
 margin-top:15px;
 margin-left:6px
}
.sidebar ul li
{
 width:100%;
 height:30px;
 line-height:30px;
 text-align:center;
 color:white;
 background-color:black;
 border:1px solid black
}

Answer (score 0):

скриптом http://jsfiddle.net/cFDre/9/